# How to display related List of Custom Object on Lightning VF page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-app-builder

I am unable to show the related objects of a custom Object.

Working with Case management System.
I added a custom object Followup (Followup__c)
Added to cases a lookup field to Followup.
Added a followup record
Edited a few cases and added the followup to that field in Cases.
In the Followup Record - Related Tab
Lists  Shows the Cases I have edited as you can see below.

Now I need to make a Visualforce page that I can further add some buttons for a custom Controller.

the VF page looks like this:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Followup__c">

      <apex:relatedList list="Cases"/>

    </apex:page>
```

And when I look at the Related in the Followup I get the message:

```
Cases not a valid child relationship name for entity Followup
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply the Cases S/B Cases__r

```
 <apex:relatedList list="Cases__r"/>
```